# Get All Events that happened on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, addeventlistener, jquery-events

Is there a way to know all the events that happened on `document` in JavaScript, without going through them one by one?

Instead of running through all events and doing this:

```
document.onDocumentContentLoaded = function(e) {
    documentLoaded = true
};

document.onmousewheel = function(e) {
    mouseWheel = true;
};
```

Is there a function I can call last thing in a page that gives me an array of all events that were called on a certain DOM (`document` in this case)?

```
$(window).on("beforeunload", function() {  
    //var events = document.GetAllEvents();          
});
```